# How to write correctly these "for" cycles in Python, my version doesnt operate

Tags: python, for-loop

```
for x in range(1, width-1):
for y in range(1, height-1):
    px = (sobel_x[0][0] * G[x-1][y-1]) + (sobel_x[0][1] * G[x][y-1]) + \
         (sobel_x[0][2] * G[x+1][y-1]) + (sobel_x[1][0] * G[x-1][y]) + \
         (sobel_x[1][1] * G[x][y]) + (sobel_x[1][2] * G[x+1][y]) + \
         (sobel_x[2][0] * G[x-1][y+1]) + (sobel_x[2][1] * G[x][y+1]) + \
         (sobel_x[2][2] * G[x+1][y+1])

    py = (sobel_y[0][0] * G[x-1][y-1]) + (sobel_y[0][1] * G[x][y-1]) + \
         (sobel_y[0][2] * G[x+1][y-1]) + (sobel_y[1][0] * G[x-1][y]) + \
         (sobel_y[1][1] * G[x][y]) + (sobel_y[1][2] * G[x+1][y]) + \
         (sobel_y[2][0] * G[x-1][y+1]) + (sobel_y[2][1] * G[x][y+1]) + \
         (sobel_y[2][2] * G[x+1][y+1])
```

How to write correctly these "for" cycles in Python, my version doesnt operate, 
it brings back an error: "unexpected indent" in front of varibale py.

Comment: All code inside first loop should also be indented

Answer (score 1):

Your script is using both tabs and spaces for indents.
On Unix you can see the tabs (indicated by `^I`) using `cat -A`:

```
% cat -A ~/tmp/data
    for x in range(1, width-1):$
    for y in range(1, height-1):$
        px = (sobel_x[0][0] * G[x-1][y-1]) + (sobel_x[0][1] * G[x][y-1]) + \$
             (sobel_x[0][2] * G[x+1][y-1]) + (sobel_x[1][0] * G[x-1][y]) + \$
             (sobel_x[1][1] * G[x][y]) + (sobel_x[1][2] * G[x+1][y]) + \$
             (sobel_x[2][0] * G[x-1][y+1]) + (sobel_x[2][1] * G[x][y+1]) + \$
             (sobel_x[2][2] * G[x+1][y+1])$
^I^I$
^I^Ipy = (sobel_y[0][0] * G[x-1][y-1]) + (sobel_y[0][1] * G[x][y-1]) + \$
             (sobel_y[0][2] * G[x+1][y-1]) + (sobel_y[1][0] * G[x-1][y]) + \$
             (sobel_y[1][1] * G[x][y]) + (sobel_y[1][2] * G[x+1][y]) + \$
             (sobel_y[2][0] * G[x-1][y+1]) + (sobel_y[2][1] * G[x][y+1]) + \$
             (sobel_y[2][2] * G[x+1][y+1])$
```

Make sure you use only spaces (or only tabs) for indentation. (If using 4-space indentation, which is the convention, it helps also to use a text editor which can be configured to insert spaces when you press TAB).

Answer (score 0):

The edit view shows that you're mixing tabs and spaces. Don't do that; convert the tabs to spaces, or Python will misunderstand your indentation. (I'm assuming your actual code has an indent after the first line, since otherwise the error message would have been different.)